# C# - Store and then update a property

Tags: compact-framework, .net-2.0, properties, c#-2.0

Evening all,

I've written a transfer application that needs to perform an update, then update a date corresponding to that update. I.e.

```
string content = string.Empty;
IIvdManager manager;
DateTime configDate;

if (table == Tables.Asset)
{
    content = WebService.GetTblAsset(companyId);
    manager = ivdData.Instance.Asset;
    configDate = ivdConfig.LAST_UPDATE_ASSET;
}
else if (table == Tables.Site)
{
    content = WebService.GetTblSite(companyId);
    manager = ivdData.Instance.Site;
    configDate = ivdConfig.LAST_UPDATE_SITE;
}
else if (table...)
{
    ...
}

if (content.Length > 0)
{
    if (UpdateManager(manager, content))
    {
        configDate = DateTime.Now;
    }

}
```

What I want is for the configDate property to update the corresponding Date Get/Set in my ivdConfig Static Class.

How can I do this?

Comment: I am confused a bit here... configDate is not a property.  It is a local variable, it seems.

Comment: Yes, it is - I know it doesn't work, however I need a way to make it be able to update the Date in the other static ivdConfig class

Comment: I am sorry, but no, configDate is not a C# property in the code above.  Depending on where it lives, it is either a field or a local variable, but it is not a property (properties have get and/or set)

Comment: the ivdConfig items are properties (with a get/set), I know the configDate isn't a property and is just a type, however I was asking how to store a property somehow from my ivdConfig class and then update it at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered the state pattern?

Subclass your table (the table variable) and add a virtual method (Update() perhaps?) that you then override in each specific table type. This will completely remove the else ifs as it will just become:

```
table.Update();
```

Pass down any objects you need to this call and then get the value back from the table (as it can update its own specific date property within its implementation of Update()).

I apologise if I have the wrong end of the stick but i'm not 100% sure what you are asking to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I think this is good code, but is this what you are looking for?

```
private DateTime configDate;

private DateTime ConfigDate
{
  get { return configDate; }
  set 
  {
    configDate = value;
    ivdConfig.TheDate = value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as simple as you need to do this:

```
manager.Date = configDate;
```

Which means I'm almost certainly wrong....

Answer (score 0):

DateTime type is a value type, so the code above will just copy the value of ivdConfig.LAST_UPDATE_SITE to dateToUpdate and not the reference to.

To solve you problem you can do the following:

```
if (table == Tables.Asset)
{
    content = WebService.GetTblAsset(companyId);
    manager = ivdData.Instance.Asset;
}
else if (table == Tables.Site)
{
    content = WebService.GetTblSite(companyId);
    manager = ivdData.Instance.Site;
}
else if (table...)
{
    ...
}

if ((content.Length > 0) && UpdateManager(manager, content))
{
    DateTime updateDate = DateTime.Now;

    if (table == Tables.Asset)
    {
        ivdConfig.LAST_UPDATE_ASSET = updateDate;
    }
    else if (table == Tables.Site)
    {
        ivdConfig.LAST_UPDATE_SITE = updateDate;
    }
    else if (table...)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is something that I wanted to avoid due to the number of tables I have to deal with. However, if that's the only way, then I guess I'm stuck to following this pattern!

Answer (score 0):

Well there does happen to be the PropertyInfo.SetValue method.